# Code igniter MySQL AES with active records?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, codeigniter, aes

How would i use code igniters active records to insert/update/select data from a database using mysql's built in aes encrypt/decrypt functions?

I know i could just use the normal sql query, but i'd like to use active records ideally.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the code provided previously:

```
$this->db->set('password',"AES_ENCRYPT('{$data['password']}','my_key')",FALSE);
```

you should still escape the password before passing it into db->set

use:

```
$pass = $this->db->escape($data['password']);
```

That way if the password contains special chars it won't kill the query

Comment: Nice addition Kris, worth an upvote in my books, welcome to SO ;)

Comment: ta :)  I thought it a good idea to help someone here given the number of times I've found solutions to my problems without even having to ask the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use AES_Encrypt if you turn off escaping for that particular clause by passing FALSE as the last parameter:

```
$pass = $this->db->escape($data['password']);
$this->db->set('password', "AES_ENCRYPT('{$pass}','my_key')", FALSE);
```

Also point you to the CI built-in [Encryption Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html), and an article on considering [1-way encryption](http://www.haughin.com/2008/02/17/handling-passwords-in-codeigniter/).